# spray-can simple-http-server example how are Bound messages handled?

Tags: scala, akka, spray

In the spray-can HTTP server example, when I run the server, I don't see any "Bound" message showing up in the log:

https://github.com/spray/spray/tree/master/examples/spray-can/simple-http-server/src/main

However, if I try to create my own server, and ignore the `Bound` message I get them going to dead-letters:

```
$ sbt run
[info] Set current project to pingpong (in build file:/D:/Projects/pingpong/)
[info] Updating {file:/D:/Projects/pingpong/}pingpong...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Running drozdyuk.pingpong.Main
[INFO] [08/03/2015 20:05:47.246] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka
://default/user/IO-HTTP/listener-0] Bound to localhost/127.0.0.1:8081
[INFO] [08/03/2015 20:05:47.246] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka
://default/deadLetters] Message [akka.io.Tcp$Bound] from Actor[akka://default/us
er/IO-HTTP/listener-0#-892116855] to Actor[akka://default/deadLetters] was not d
elivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjust
ed with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letter
s-during-shutdown'.
```

My question is mainly out of curiosity, how does the `Bound` message get handled in the example? Is it some kind of logging that swallows them or something else?

Code for my `Main.scala`:

```
package drozdyuk.pingpong

import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.io.IO
import spray.can.Http

object Main extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()

  // the handler actor replies to incoming HttpRequests
  val handler = system.actorOf(Props[WebService], name = "handler")

  val PORT = 8081
  val DOMAIN = "localhost"
  IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(handler, interface = DOMAIN, port = PORT)
}
```

and my `WebService.scala`:

```
package drozdyuk.pingpong

import akka.actor._
import spray.http.HttpMethods.{GET}
import spray.can.Http
import spray.http.{HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Uri}

class WebService extends Actor with ActorLogging {
    def receive = {
      // New connection - register self as handler
      case _: Http.Connected => sender ! Http.Register(self)

      case HttpRequest(GET, Uri.Path("/ping"), _, _, _) =>
        sender ! HttpResponse(entity = "pong")

      case HttpRequest(GET, Uri.Path("/pong"), _, _, _) =>
        sender ! HttpResponse(entity = "ping")


      case _: HttpRequest => sender ! HttpResponse(status = 404, entity = "Unknown resource!")


    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use another version of `tell` in your `Main`:

```
IO(Http).tell(Http.Bind(handler, interface = DOMAIN, port = PORT), sender = handler)
```

And then handle `Bound` message in your WebService:

```
class WebService extends Actor with ActorLogging {
    def receive = {
        case Http.Bound(address) =>
        //all other cases...
    }
}
```

In your case you are using

```
def !(message: Any)(implicit sender: ActorRef = Actor.noSender): Unit
```

and there is no implicit sender in scope of `Main` so default `noSender` will be used.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works great for me:

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.io._
import spray.can.Http
import spray.http.HttpResponse
import spray.http.HttpRequest
import spray.http.Uri
import spray.http.HttpMethods.{GET}

class WebService extends Actor with ActorLogging {
    def receive = {
        case _: Http.Connected => sender ! Http.Register(self)

        case _: HttpRequest => sender ! HttpResponse(status = 404, entity =     "Unknown resource!")

        case HttpRequest(GET, Uri.Path("/ping"), _, _, _) =>
                    sender ! HttpResponse(entity = "pong")

        //all other cases...
    }
}

object TestSpray extends App {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem()
    val myListener: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props[WebService], name = "handler")
    IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(myListener, interface = "localhost", port = 8080)
}
```